# Arduino C++ destructor?

Tags: c++, arduino

I know that in Arduino you can't use `delete`. So when does the destructor defined in C++ classes gets called?

Similarly, if I want to create a pointer to array, I would have to use `malloc` and `free`?

Comment: Yes, `malloc` and `free`

Comment: Seems like there are two questions here: "When does the destructor get called in Standard C++?" and "Which of these cases are supported by the Arduino C++ implementation?"  But I thought that Arduino doesn't use C++ (although C++ compilers certainly exist for the hardware, Arduino is more than just hardware).

Comment: @BenVoigt, some years ago I had to write programs on `AVR` platform. It was `g++` port for the platform, but actually standard library missed new and delete. I think, it is not implemented, because you probably might want use your own dynamic memory manager, that will be more effective in low memory circumstances.

Comment: Interesting. If I can just replace every `new` with `malloc` and placement-new, and `delete` with manual destructor call and `free`, then what's the objection for having `delete` on Ardiuno?

Comment: @Lol4t0: Exactly, if this is g++ on AVR it should be called that, not "Arduino".

Answer (score 2):

The destructor is called when the object is destroyed. For automatic (on stack) variables, it's called after leaving its scope (`{}`). Read more about [automatic variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable).

Answer (score 0):

The destructor gets called when the variable goes out of scope or `delete`'d. This means, if you have no `delete` you can *only* create non-[POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) structures in *automatic* memory.

You *cannot* use `malloc` and `free`, because constructors and destructors *will not be called*.

But, you can try create your own `new` and `delete` like this:

```
void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    void* mem = malloc(size);
    if (!mem) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
    return mem;
}

void operator delete(void* ptr)
{
    free(ptr);
}

void* operator new[] (size_t size)
{
    return (operator new)(size);
}

void operator delete[](void* ptr)
{
    return (operator delete)(ptr);
}
```

Comment: objects are also destroyed when you call the destructor directly, but that's pretty rare so its acceptable to me that you didnt mention it.  Ardino sounds like a strange platform, are you sure this works on it?

Comment: @MooingDuck, `Arduino` is just `AVR` platform with cookies (some IDE  features + USB boot loader). I believe, if author uses `C++`, it is actually `gcc` port for `AVR`. I used such trick for `g++` on `AVR` and I googled a little before posting and found it is possible on `Arduino`.

Comment: Do not use throw on Arduino, please (exceptions are not supported).

Comment: Indeed, how do you want to throw when there is no OS to maintain apps ?

Comment: OS support is not required for `throw`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you can use `delete` in Arduino with anything that's created with `new`.

And the `destructor` is called when you deleted.

And Yes about `malloc` and `free`.

```
class MyClass {
  private:
    char *_var;
  public:
    MyClass(int size) { // Constructor
      _var = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
      ...
    }

  ~MyClass() { // Destructor
    free( _var );
  }
  ...
}
```