# Why don't I receive the data that is in my byte array?

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I'm a beginner with C++ and trying to create a program for my Arduino. The code below compiles fine, but the result is different from what I expect it to be.

What I expect to receive on my PC is: 0x04 , 0x61 , 0x62 , 0x63.

What I receive on my PC is: 0xff 0x00 0xb1 0x00.

I tried to minimize the code in such a way that it only addresses the problem that I run in to.

```
byte *assembleFrame() {
  byte frame[] = { 4 , 'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' };
  return frame;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin( 115200 );
};

void loop() {
  byte *frame = assembleFrame();
  Serial.write( frame , 4 );
  // should send 0x04 0x61 0x62 0x63, leaving out 0x64 being 5th element.
  while ( 1 ) {
  }
}
```

I think it has something to do with pointers, but can't figure it out.

FYI:

```
Serial.write( buf , len ) arguments:    
  buf: an array to send as a series of bytes
  len: the length of the buffer
```

**EDIT:**
Solution so far:

```
int assembleFrame( byte *frame ) {
  int octetCounter = 0;
  frame[ octetCounter++ ] = 'A'; // preamble
  frame[ octetCounter++ ] = 'B'; // preamble
  frame[ octetCounter++ ] = 0;   // frame length set at end of function
  frame[ octetCounter++ ] = h;
  frame[ octetCounter++ ] = m;
  frame[ octetCounter++ ] = s;
  frame[ 2 ] = octetCounter;  // frame length

  return frame[ 2 ];
}

void loop() {
  int bytes_in_frame = assembleFrame( frame );
  Serial.write( frame, bytes_in_frame ); // assuming ptr + bytes to send
  delay( 1000 );
}
```

It gives the desired result.

Comment: Did you see that I updated my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+Krister's answer is a good one, I would improve on it by suggesting you pass the buffer into your assembly function, if at all possible.

```
/* Takes in an array of bytes with at least the given size, returns
 * the number of bytes written into the frame.
 */
int assembleFrame(byte *frame, int frame_size) {
  frame[0] =  4;
  frame[1] = 'a';
  frame[2] = 'b';
  frame[3] = 'c';
  frame[4] = 'd';
  return 5; // only used five bytes in the frame
}

  /* then in loop() */
  byte frame[10];
  bytes_in_frame = assembleFrame(frame, 10);
  someDataSendingFunction(frame, bytes_in_frame); // assuming ptr + bytes to send
```

That way you don't create the possibility of a memory leak later on.

Comment: Or you can just return an `std::vector<byte>`.

Comment: @caskey: I'll have to study this in more detail tomorrow (bed time here). Why are you returning 5? I'd expect 10 as it is the size of the array. Or do you mean max 10, actual size 5?

Comment: @AndréCaron: I'm lost. Can you reference some easy reading on your suggestion?

Comment: @jippie: You can just write `std::vector<byte> assembleFrame(){std::vector<byte> frame(5); frame[0] = ...; return frame;}`.  You can find detailed class references and tutorials online.  Here's a [vector tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm) that looks decent at first glance.

Comment: @jippi It's a common convention, as noted in the comment above the function, to return how much you actually wrote into the passed in array.  I'll edit the code to remove the '...'.  The size information passed in is so that if the assembleFrame function might produce a variable-length result then it can check that the caller gave it enough space rather than simply overrun the array.

Comment: @AndréCaron: arduino isn't conforming C++, they don't really have the containers, nor heap memory, nor other stuff.  Otherwise that would have been a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your assembleFrame() function returns a local variable that will run out of scope when the function returns. You could do something like this:

```
 byte* assembleFrame() {
      byte* frame = new byte[5];
      frame[0] = 4;
      frame[1] = 'a';
      frame[2] = 'b';
      frame[3] = 'c';
      frame[4] = 'd';
      return frame;
 }
```

*Note* that the memory returned by assembleFrame() then should be freed using:

```
void loop() {
   byte* frame = assembleFrame();
   Serial.write( frame , frame[ 0 ] );
   // release the memory allocated by assembleFrame()
   delete [] frame;
   while ( 1 ) {
   }
}
```

Comment: 1) sketch_apr09b.cpp: In function ‘byte* assembleFrame()’:
sketch_apr09b.cpp:7:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token   2) delete [] frame should go into the main loop?

Comment: Yes, you should use `delete [] frame` on the pointer returned from `assembledFrame()` after you finished using it.

Comment: Please refer to my EDIT in the original post. It works works apart from the delete. Also from my experience with Perl, I don't like defining global variables if it isn't necessary so I'm trying to understand why I should now.

Comment: Also, like already said, if you will call this function in a loop, consider using a constant or static array instead.

Comment: `delete` is not supported on Arduino.

Comment: Can I use C++ on the AVR?  http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as being said, you got dangling pointer and underfined behaviour for now. If you will enable warnings (`-Wall`) you will get

> warning: address of local variable 'frame' returned

As far, as Arduino is embedding and using dynamic dynamic memory management is unpleasant with embedded ([you cannot even call new by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805829/arduino-c-destructor/980607), hehe) due to resource limitations, you may want use the following soultions:

1. make `frame` static:

   ```
   char *assembleFrame() {
       static char frame[] = { 'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd', 0 };
       return frame;
   }
   ```

   Of cause, if you change array in your code after `assembleFrame` call, this changing will persist.
2. make `frame` `const` pointer and return string

   ```
   const char *assembleFrame() {
       const char* frame = "abcd\0";
       return frame;
   }
   ```

Comment: I can't make frame static, because it needs to be replaced with the actual data that is read from the I/O ports. Correct me if I'm wrong (I am a beginner after all), but using constants will move the data into flash memory and I can not change its contents while running the code.

Comment: @jippie, you cannot use my 2nd example, but you still can use 1st.  It has much common with global array,  actually. Also consider using caskey variant.